# How to call activity methods from cordova plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How to call methods inside an activity class from cordova plugin class?

```
// Plugin class
public class BLEPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("greet")) {
            String name = args.getString(0);
            String message = "Hello, " + name;
            //callbackContext.success(message);
            this.greet(message, callbackContext);
        } else if (action.equals("isBLESupported")) {
            this.isBLESupported(callbackContext);
        }
        return true;
    }


    // Returns true if BLE is supported.
    private void isBLESupported(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        boolean isSupported = .. ?  // how to access MainActivity method?
        Log.w(TAG, "isSupported: " + isSupported);
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("isSupported", isSupported);
        } catch (JSONException execp) {}
        callbackContext.success(params);
    }
}


// Main activity
// ..
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ..
    }

    // How to access this method?
    public boolean isBLESupported() {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try static method ?  public static boolean isBLESupported()

Comment: I'm getting `getPackageManager()` cannot be referenced from static context error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your MainActivity create static Method

```
public static boolean isBLESupported(Context c) {

    System.out.println("Activity");
    return c.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
}
```

and in your Cordovaplugin change your method

```
// Returns true if BLE is supported.
private void isBLESupported(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    boolean isSupported = MainActivity.isBLESupported(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.w(TAG, "isSupported: " + isSupported);
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("isSupported", isSupported);
    } catch (JSONException execp) {}
    callbackContext.success(params);
}
```

Or you can directly check boolean from plugin class by cordova context

```
 boolean isSupported = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
```